# If the multiplicity of $a$ in $f$ (a polynomial) is equal to $1$ if and only if $(Df)(a)\ne 0$

Tags: calculus

If the multiplicity of $a$ in f (a polynomial) is equal to 1 if and only if $(Df)(a)\ne 0$

I did this:

If $a$ is a root then $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)$

applying derivate product

$f(x)'=(x-a)'q(x)+(x-a)q'(x)$ evaluating at $a$ then

$f(a)'=(1)q(a)+(x-a)q'(a)$ but $(x-a)=0$ because $x=a$ is a root

$f(a)'=q(a)+0q(a)'$

$f(a)'=q(a)$ but we can ensure that $q(a)\neq{}0$ because if $q(a)=0$ then the multiplicity of $a$ going to greater than one

I did the first part but I don't know who can I do the second part? if  $(Df)(a)\neq{} 0
 \Rightarrow{}$ the multiplicity of $a$ is $1$.

Thanks for everything,

Have a nice day :D

Comment: Hint: Suppose the multiplicity is not $1$. Then $(x-a)^2$ divides $f$, so $f(x)=(x-a)^2g(x)$ for some polynomial $g$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  if the multiplicity is not 1, then  $(Df)(a)=0$. I proved this before, thanks for you help

Comment: But a formal proof that if  (Df)(a)≠0 ⇒ the multiplicity of a is 1, Just this part? thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Then why the question at the end of your post? It is exactly equivalent to this.

Comment: @AndréNicolas    Yes but in  "if the multiplicity is not 1, then (Df)(a)=0" I can't do the part that  if (Df)(a)=0 ⇒ the multiplicity is greater that 1, I have an incomplete proof :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for a proof that if $f(a)=0$ and the derivative of $f$ at $a$ is not equal to $0$, then the multiplicity of $a$ is $1$.

Suppose to the contrary that $f'(a)\ne 0$ and the multiplicity is **greater** than $1$. Then by the definition of multiplicity, $(x-a)^2$ divides $f$. So there is a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $f(x)=(x-a)^2 g(x)$.

Differentiate. We get $f'(x)=(x-a)^2g'(x)+2(x-a)g(x)$. It follows that $f'(a)=0$, contradicting the assumption that $f'(a)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there as there were really no one-way implications.
Given a root $a$, you write $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ and find $f'(a)=q(a)$.
Now the root $a$ is a multiple root iff $(x-a)^2$ divides $f$ iff $(x-a)$ divides $q$ iff $q(a)=0$ iff $f'(a)=0$. Done.